# How to modify a component's property in a function?

Tags: react-native, countdown, pause

I'm trying to learn react and how to use third party components, what I'm trying to do now is to use the component that I installed from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-countdown-component

**objective:**

The Countdown component has a "Props" called "running" which I would like to modify when I "click" on the component.

**code:**

the code that I'm using is just a fresh new app created using "expo init MyApp", then I've pasted in the code to import and generate the component

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-countdown-component
import CountDown from 'react-native-countdown-component';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>

      <CountDown
        until={60}
        size={30}
        //onFinish={() => alert('Finished')}
        digitStyle={{backgroundColor: '#FFF'}}
        digitTxtStyle={{color: '#1CC625'}}
        timeToShow={['M', 'S']}
        timeLabels={{m: '', s: ''}}
        showSeparator={true}      
        onPress={() =>
          {
            this.setState({running:true});
          }}
          running={false}
        />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

what is the correct way to modify the "running" property of the Countdown component when the component is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start using state properly. For this time I will use React Hooks, it's simpler than using the traditional functional or class components. [See more](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Every time state is updated, it will cause component to rerender with the new value.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-countdown-component
import CountDown from 'react-native-countdown-component';

export default function App() {
  const [isRunning, setRunning] = useState(false) //React Hooks
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <CountDown
        until={60}
        size={30}
        //onFinish={() => alert('Finished')}
        digitStyle={{backgroundColor: '#FFF'}}
        digitTxtStyle={{color: '#1CC625'}}
        timeToShow={['M', 'S']}
        timeLabels={{m: '', s: ''}}
        showSeparator={true}      
        //When component is pressed, updates state to true
        onPress={() => { setRunning(true); }}
        running={isRunning} 
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: thank you!!! I modified the onPress event to make it work as a toggle, onPress={() => { setRunning(!isRunning); }}

Answer (score 0):

I found another way, that requires a new class but I prefer Ian Steban Vasco's answer.

the solution that I found out was to create a new component that will hold the "state" for the Countdown component, then use the MyCountdown component in the main method instead of directly using the Countdown component

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-countdown-component
import CountDown from 'react-native-countdown-component';
export default class MyCountdown extends React.Component{
    state = {
        running: false
    };
    handleOnPress = () =>{
        this.setState({running:!this.state.running});
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <CountDown
                until={60}
                size={30}
                //onFinish={() => alert('Finished')}
                digitStyle={{backgroundColor: '#FFF'}}
                digitTxtStyle={{color: '#1CC625'}}
                timeToShow={['M', 'S']}
                timeLabels={{m: '', s: ''}}
                showSeparator={true}      
                onPress={this.handleOnPress}
                running={this.state.running}
              />
        );
    }
}
```